# Set icon in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, icons, jframe, imageicon

I want to change the icon of the project instead of java icon. When the program icon is being displayed in status bar, it should be displaying the customized icon instead of default java icon.

I am using the following code. Please suggest me what's wrong in this code.

```
class newframe extends JFrame 
{

    Container cp;
    newframe()
    {
        cp=this.getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(null);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        newframe frm= new newframe(); 

        frm.setbounds(0,0,1000,800);
        frm.setVisible(true);
        ImageIcon im1= new ImageIcon("path upto image");
        frm.setIconImage(im1.getImage());
    }
}
```

Comment: i also want to change size and shape of icon

Comment: I want a pony ..and an ice-cream.  My advice is to ask one question per question, when you get a good answer, accept it, and when you get a bad answer, ask the provider for more detail.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I want a helicopter ... while were wishing

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [Window#setImageIcons(List)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages%28java.util.List%29) which takes a list of `Image`, which allows you to provide a number of different sized icons and let the underlying platform to pick the best one...

Comment: You may also want to look at [Class#getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) for loading embedded images from within Jar's on the classpath

Comment: @Mad Good idea re. `setIcons(..)` though perhaps we should get this sorted with ***any*** icon before going on to worry about assigning multiple icons (e.g. as seen in [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui)). ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer _setImageIcons(List)_ cool - my learn item of the day :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
..new ImageIcon("path upto image");
```

A frame icon will typically be an embedded-resource, so must be accessed by `URL` rather than (a `String` representing a path to) a `File`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things that would be keeping it from compiling.  First:

```
frm.setbounds(0,0,1000,800);
```

Your "setbounds" should have a capital B.  Typically, functions will be cased such that the first letter of the first word is lowercased, and subsequent words are upper-cased. See this link for the doc on setBounds: [setBounds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

There's a second issue in your ImageIcon path.  Its hard to say if that came right from your code or if you removed the path for the sake of the example, but Andrew Thompson has addressed that adequately.

Comment: *"the example you gave wouldn't compile for the reason given by Andrew."*  The `new ImageIcon("path upto image");` would have compiled literally like that.  Though it would not find the resource as a `File` (or `URL`) at run-time.  +1 for spotting the lower case method name.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson.  I'll edit that for correctness; thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Great edit.   And thanks for reminding me with *"its hard to say if that came right from your code or if you removed the path for the sake of the example"* that I need to leave a message with the OP.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: dear sir code is running now but i want to change the size of icon and shape from rectangle to circular

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the decleration of the imageicon. What you should do is instead of getting the direct path, do something like this:

`ImageIcon im1= new ImageIcon("Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().
getImage(getClass().getResource("path upto image"))");`
I do this with all of my applications, and it works every time.